# How do i reference 1 Mongoose Schema inside another as its property?

Tags: javascript, express, mongoose-schema

I am trying to make a store app and have created two mongoose schemas. Order.js and Product.js, I want to reference the product schema as a property of the order schema.

*Order.js*

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Product=require('../models/product.js');

const orderSchema = new mongoose.Schema(

    {
        date: {
             type:Date, 
             default: Date.now},
        customerName: String,
        customerAddress: String,
        creditCard: Number,
        products:[] //product model
   
    },
     { timestamps: true }
);
```

*product.js*

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const productSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
    {
        name: String,
        price: Number,
        category: String
    },
    { timestamps: true }
);

const Product = mongoose.model('Product', productSchema);
module.exports= Product;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my approach when it comes to nested schemas in mongoose :
first you have to create an object of your Product schema , to avoid duplicating your Product model , you can create an object :

> product

with your fields , then create your Product schema by simply `const Product = new Schema(product);` , then you can import the product object here in your order.js and declare your schema as follows :

```
import product;
const Order = new Schema({
......
......
order : {
   type : product , 
   ......
}
})
```